# Update GridView using DropDownList of DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am using V2005 C#.

I have a GridView in my .aspx page, and I am able to update my database using DropDownList controls in my EditItemTemplate.

DDL for my Gender column:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'>
                <asp:ListItem>M</asp:ListItem>  
                <asp:ListItem>F</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

In my DDL EditItemTemplate for my Gender column, I used hard coded values, and it works.

However, I tried to implement DDL on another column. This time, I used a SqlDataSource which selects data from another table, instead of using fixed values, but they gave me an error instead:
`'DropDownList3' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.Parameter name: value`

I tried to implement `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("MemberType") %>'` as well, but it did not work.

Below is the code for my `MemberType` DDL EditItemTemplate:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MemberType" SortExpression="MemberType">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
                DataTextField="MemberType" DataValueField="MemberType" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("MemberType") %>'>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MemberType") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Anyone know what is wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well...maybe this is a silly question, but is the value actually in the list returned in the SqlDatasource SELECT query?  A common issue is that if there is no NULL value in your query then it is not in the list so as soon as you switch to edit mode you throw an error because the default value is null.

I have a Misc function in my library that accepts a DropDownList reference and adds a blank row.

**EDIT to add some code:**

We use Telerik Rad Controls so this is for a RadComboBox but since that control just extends DropDownList (I think, they may have extended TextBox...) the syntax for adding an empty item should be similar to what I have below.

```
// If there is already an empty row, we will not add an aditional empty row
        RadComboBoxItem  emptyItem = null;
        emptyItem = rcbObject.FindItemByValue(null) ?? rcbObject.FindItemByValue("");

        if (emptyItem !=null)
            return;

        // Add a Empty(null) item to the dropdown list
        RadComboBoxItem item_null = new RadComboBoxItem();

        item_null.Text = "";
        item_null.Value = null;
        rcbObject.Items.Insert(0, item_null);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. so how do I add the values from my datasource and input them into my DLL?